# TypeError: addRecord() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val9'

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I want to insert my data to PostgreSQL with psycopg2.

I created addRecord definition like that:

```
def addRecord(self, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9):
        query = """
        INSERT INTO stories (
        val1, 
        val2,
        val3, 
        val4, 
        val5, 
        val6, 
        val7, 
        val8, 
        val9) 
        VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        self.cursor.execute(query, (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5,val6, val7, val8, val9))
        self.connection.commit()
```

and I call this addRecord definition like that:

```
        print("Val9 value is " + val9) ===============================>>>>>IT'S WORKING 
        DatabaseConnection.addRecord(
            val1, 
            val2, 
            val3,
            val4, 
            val5, 
            val6, 
            val7, 
            val8, 
            val9)
```

And the output like that:

```
Val9 value is 12345asdas
...
...
TypeError: addRecord() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val9'
```

Why Im getting this error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addRecord` method references `self` (`self.cursor` & `self.connection`) which is typically the *instance* variable. You've called addRecord using `DatabaseConnection.addRecord(...)`. Quite likely, that needs to be `DatabaseConnection().addRecord(...)` → Note the parenttheses after `DatabaseConnection`. And that will only work if your class `__init__()` already has the needed defaults to create the connection.

Typically, it should be something like:

```py
conn = DatabaseConnection()
conn.addRecord(...)
conn.addRecord(...)
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `addRecord()` doesn't seem to be a class method, so `self` becomes a normal parameter. Remove that, because with that there are 10 parameters,and val1 becomes value of self variable.

Comment: _"doesn't seem to be a class method"_ ? Then the first param would be the class `cls` and since Python doesn't care about the name, it wouldn't pop that error. Perhaps you meant `staticmethod`? Coz then the error would be exactly this, with the fix being your explanation.